# How do I make sense of this Math.round result?

Tags: java

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA  to write a java program to compute and print the value of Math.round(6.022e23)

```
public class MathRound {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long value = Math.round(6.022e23);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

after I compile and execute I get:

9223372036854775807

However, I know the answer to be 602200000000000000000000.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you were wondering what that number is: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q10571632

Comment: Java Language Specification [4.2.1. Integral Types and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1): "*The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:  ... For `long`, from `-9223372036854775808` to `9223372036854775807`, inclusive*" - and [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)) of `round()`: "*Returns the closest long to the argument,  ...*" (or [`Long.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE))

Comment: damn I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

For my yo can use this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double value = 6.022e23;
    BigDecimal valueD = BigDecimal.valueOf(value).setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(valueD);
}
```

this converts it to bigdecimal, maybe later you can convert it to the data type you want, or pass it to a string and then to a long or whatever you want.
And RoundingMode you have a lot options : down, floor, half_up,etc